# set and get value from cookie not work in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I would like to set and get value in cookie but it doesn't work:

```
    Cookie::queue('online_payment_id', "1", 15);

    $value = Cookie::get('online_payment_id');
    dd($value);
```

`dd()` returns `null`;

Answer (score 0):

To get a fresh cookie from the jar you can use `$value = Cookie::queued('online_payment_id')`. That cookie was queued, but it wasn't sent yet.

However IMHO it's way easier to work with

```
request()->cookie('online_payment_id');
```

and

```
response()->cookie('online_payment_id', "1", 15);
```

Comment: I got this message: `Method cookie does not exist.`

Comment: This is the correct syntax for Laravel 5.3 or later. Older versions had a slightly different syntax, as explained in the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests#cookies